# MVC 3 Route in Intranet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I developed a web site in MVC, now I need put this web site in production server. But, in my machine the url is http:\localhost:1600\ but in the server the site ist http:\10.132.130.122\MyIGF

I think this problem are about routes because my website has this code in HTML

```
<link href="/Contenct/site.css" />
<a href="/Home/Login">Login</a>
```

And / not is the route correct to site.

The correct to production server is

```
<link href="MyIGF/Contenct/site.css" />
<a href="MyIGF/Home/Login">Login</a>
```

Any helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a route problem, its a fundamental flaw with the way your links are created.

If you use the `Url.Content` directive, mvc will put the correct path on your content files.

```
<input type="image" src="<%:Url.Content("~/img/submit.png")%>" />
```

For links to actions, there is also `Url.Action` which would create the correct link.

```
<a href="<%:Url.Action("Home", "Login")%>">Login</a>
```

Comment: I don't used <%:Url.Content("~/img/submit.png")%> to not hight a server, them I write the plain HTML.

Comment: I don't user <%:Url.Content("~/img/submit.png")%> to not **weigh** a server, them I write the plain HTML. I think this is a best pratics.